# Telegram: links from Amazon don't always open in the app

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm running a Telegram network where I post discounts from Amazon on a daily basis.

Now this is the problem: when I click on the links from my smartphone, they **don't always** open the Amazon app, but **sometimes** Telegram opens the page in its in-app browser. And that's a problem for me because users would never finalize a purchase by logging in again on Amazon from the Telegram browser - of course they go open the Amazon app and buy from there, and I get no commissions.

Now... is there some logic behind that? How does it work? I couldn't find a pattern for it: just sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the links open the Amazon app, sometimes they don't.

I used to shorten the links using Bit.ly, and thought it could be the problem (maybe the "amzn.to" wasn't recognized?), but nope, even using the long form links, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to chat setting of Telegram and off the option to open in app link